# Wordpress show post without widgets, header, footer

Tags: wordpress

We use Wordpress for the company blog. We would like to show some of the posts in a popover (or light box) on another website. To do that, we need to be able to show just the post's contents without the widgets, header, footer, etc.

So, for example, look at this post:
http://wordpress.org/news/2014/07/wordpress-4-0-beta-1/

Imagine being able to use a special URL, like http://wordpress.org/news/2014/07/wordpress-4-0-beta-1/?postOnly=true where the top header would be removed (the black stuff), all the widgets on the side bar, the entire footer, etc.

Only thing remaining would be the headline, when posted and by who, and the actual post contents.

Any ideas?

Comment: In response to @Hipolith and ssergei - I forgot to mention I can't change the site's main template as it doubles as a full blown site. It look like I'm looking at a way of running two templates on the same content - one is a default template and another is only for these special links.

Answer (score 3):

Create a very simple page template with code similar to this:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Clean Page Template
*/
wp_head(); 

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
       the_content(); 
    endwhile; 
endif;

wp_footer();
```

Then just set this template in the post edit screen.

Answer (score 0):

If You can modify theme You're using it's simple to do - just check if postOnly parameter is set and set to true in places that render header, footer etc. If so, simply don't render it.

Comment: where is this postOnly parameter? I couldn't find it in wordpress documentation

Comment: @AlexandruRada the "postOnly" param was an example param yi1 wanted to pass in the URL - it's not a part of the Wordpress and it doesn't even have to be named "postOnly". You can pass any param via query string and then in your template (or plugin or wherever) do some action based on the value of that param

Comment: thanks. I've upgraded to 4.7 and it has the API integrated into the core now.